# Update nested array elements in Mongo DB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have "Project" collection as below. I would like to update email domain in "users" & "owners" to "@mailm365.com"

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("637e0af92ce49a1a816807bc"),
"title" : "Project-1",
"description" : "Project-1 Description",
"users" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f8881823542b1b499d7b351"),
        "fullname" : "User-1",
        "email" : "user-1@mail.com"
    }
],
"owners" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f8881823542b1b499d7b351"),
        "fullname" : "User-2",
        "email" : "user-2@mail.com"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("61fb71ca294d34537dafe4c9"),
        "fullname" : "User-3",
        "email" : "user-3@mail.com"
    }
]}
```

I have tried with the following query but no luck. Any help to make this update query work?

```
db.Project.find().forEach(function(project)
{
  project.users.forEach(function(user){
    var updatedDomain = user.email.replace('@mail.com', '@mailm365.com');
    user.email = updatedDomain;
  });

  project.owners.forEach(function(owner){
    var updatedDomain = owner.email.replace('@mail.com', '@mailm365.com');
    owner.email = updatedDomain;
  });
  
  db.Project.updateOne(
    {
      _id:project._id
    },
    {
       $set:
            {
                "users": project.users,
                "owners": project.owners
            }
    }   
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Query

- you need pipeline update because you want to update based on previous value, and you also need `$split` function that is pipeline operator
- 2 times the same code
- `$map` on the array, `$this` will be the document member, and `$mergeObjects` with the new email
- new email is split the old, take the first part before the @ and
  concat it with the `@mailm365.com` new docmain name

*this does it for all users,owners if you want to do it only for some, you can add a `$cond` inside the map to do it only in specific

[PLaymongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=637e23fb424f6130d7f12168)

```js
update(
{"_id": {"$eq": ObjectId("637e0af92ce49a1a816807bc")}},
[{"$set": 
   {"users": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$users",
        "in": 
         {"$mergeObjects": 
           ["$$this",
             {"email": 
               {"$concat": 
                 [{"$first": {"$split": ["$$this.email", "@"]}},
                  "@mailm365.com"]}}]}}}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"owners": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$owners",
        "in": 
         {"$mergeObjects": 
           ["$$this",
             {"email": 
               {"$concat": 
                 [{"$first": {"$split": ["$$this.email", "@"]}},
                  "@mailm365.com"]}}]}}}}}],
{"multi": true})
```

Comment: We're on the same wavelength today.  Here's a [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zA3b6L4n5wO) with virtually the same thing.

Comment: @rickhg12hs i stole your answer+posted first :P,  i wrote the squery, see playmongo link, you might like it, its smaller